# Javascript function binding possible memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I wish I could think of a better question for my situation.

Let me give the context in code.

I have this general function intended for binding with different variations (only about 3 or 4 cases).

```js
GeneralFunction = function(helper, paramA, paramB) {
   if (paramA == "hello") {
      return helper(paramA);
   }
   return paramB;

}
```

Then I have this function to return a particular variation of general function.

```js
function getFlavorX() {
  return GeneralFunction.bind(undefined, helperX);
}
```

My concern is that the `getFlavorX()` could be called many many times (thousands), and according to  [documentation of bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), seems each call to `bind` creates a **new** function. Even for the exact same `helperX`?

So I guess I am kind of leaking function objects?

Comment: make your code smarter, to NOT create a new function that binds to helperX if you already have a function that binds to helperX :p

Comment: Yes, `bind` does create new function objects, but whether they are leaked or immediately garbage-collected depends on the rest of your code. Do you have any actual performance problems?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks! Once I thought of this memory leak concern, I changed my code to do just that. I guess I am wondering whether this is a legitimate concern or not...  What if Javascript can just automatically garbage collect these kind of things?

Comment: As comment above says, *depends on the rest of your code*

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I don't have any performance issues yet. My system currently only has maybe 4 users, the table rows are like 20 or something, but it could be 1000s once system goes to production. :D

Comment: @JaromandaX  I guess the concern is kind of legit...? So I control the number of bindings, and I shouldn't worry too much about how the rest of the code uses it...

Comment: So you're saying you are *storing* thousands of functions in that table? Then yes, you probably should cache them.

Comment: @Bergi  I am passing the result function to a third party library called Datatables, as a custom renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the concern is valid, but memory leak or not depends on rest of code. Since in my case, the variations of binding are very limited, I manually maintain the list of bindings function objects (I return an already binded function object, instead of let user codes invoke `bind` on each call).